# search file and print to the same directory

Tags: bash, find

I want to search a file by name and run a python script on it and finally print the output to the directory that contains the file. The structure looks like

> dir_a/common.txt
>   dir_b/common.txt
>   dir_c/common.txt

And so far I have came up with

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -name "common.txt" -exec cat "{}" \; | ~/myscript.py
```

myscript.py prints to the stdout. But how can I redirect the output to

> dir_a/out.txt
>   dir_b/out.txt
>   dir_c/out.txt

Answer (score 0):

Maybe small script `runmypy.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
topdir="${1:-.}"
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    dir=$(dirname "$file")
    /path/to/myscript.py < "$file" >"$dir/out.txt"
done < <(find "$topdir" -maxdepth 2 -type f -name "common.txt" -print0)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate it? I got error saying  "5: runmypy.sh: Syntax error: redirection unexpected"

Comment: You tagged the question as `bash`. This is an `bash` script. (and not `dash`, or like). Edited and added a shebang (just for sure).